# Unreal C++: How to Get Nodes in Blueprint Graph

Tags: python, c++, unreal-engine4

I’m trying to expand on our importer that I created using Unreal’s Python library so that on import it will update some of the data on node within the Blueprint Graph.

After investigating, this does not appear to be possible through Python (at least not in 4.27) as while I can get the instance of the Blueprint, I can’t get any instances of the nodes within the graph.

I’m not familiar with the C++ side of Unreal so I’m just wondering if something like this is possible through C++ and if so would any one have any example code for getting the nodes in a blueprint graph for an asset path supplied?

Comment: It would be easier and cleaner to have the data you'd like to update as a variable, connected to the node you need, and update simply the default variable's value on the Blueprint class.

Comment: Was starting to experimenting with this approach today so I'm glad to hear it's the better approach. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score -1):

For this:

1. You need to get first the Graph of that Blueprint of your interest
   like this: `Blueprint->UberGraph[0]//Here index 0 indicates the Event Graph.`
2. Now you need to create a Node type variable which will then be used to traverse the Graph:

```
for(UEdGraphNode:Graph->Nodes)
{
  Here you have got the Individual Nodes one by one from Graph and can access its functions Node-> like this
}
```